# Grouping Data with SUM of Value No Greater than a Specific Number (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, sum, grouping, array-formulas

I have series of numbers as you can see in the following table in a Google Spreadsheet:

[image: givencondition]

I want each name to form a group with other names next to it with sum of value no more than 26. If a sum is greater than 26, then it will be just forced to form to another group with another name.

So that it might look like this:

[image: desiredoutput]

In this example, A and B can form a group together since the total sum of A and B is no more than 26. C is forced to form a group just by itself since if we add D with C, the sum will be more than 26. D is also forced to form a group just by itself since if we add D with E, the sum will be more than 26.

How can I create a table with Array Formula so it looks like that?

This is the link for the sample case:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BXfJrfbtdsGP4fr9dsKxFq54nM4PnKLHauAOy5UAPbY/edit#gid=0

1. The sample case is in Sheet2
2. Column A and B are given condition
3. Column D to G are the desired outcome

Edited: sample case is changed from Sheet1 to Sheet2 so that the problem can be seen more clearly. Sheet1 is hidden to prevent confusion.

Comment: I would suggest using either a pull-down formula or a script

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using two formulas:

for group in col G `=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B,INT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*B2:B),SIGN(B2:B))/26)+1,))`

for group sum in col F `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),SUMIF(G2:G,G2:G,B2:B),))`

or using one formula in col F which will be slower:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(B2:B),{SUMIF(INT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*B2:B),SIGN(B2:B))/26)+1,INT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*B2:B),SIGN(B2:B))/26)+1,B2:B),INT(MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*B2:B),SIGN(B2:B))/26)+1},))
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou, but it seems that your solution doesn't always work somehow. I just updated the case and you can see it in Sheet2 with the same link. As you can see in Sheet2, if value on C is changed to 24, when your formula is applied, it seems to be bugging in group 4. Group 4 sum of value is 34 which means it contains value more than 26. Can you help with this?